# Error on deploy of firebase push notification function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification

Im trying to use firebase push notification services for my app. for this i have set up firebase push notification dependency in my app and also have installed node.js and firebase tools. when i use firebase deploy on the directory to deploy the functions i get this error

```
40:14  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-
nesting
41:25  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-
return

✖ 2 problems (1 error, 1 warning)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
```

this is the index.js file

```js
'use strict'


const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require ('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_id}/{notification_id}')
       .onWrite(event => 
    {
     const receiver_id = event.params.receiver_id;
     
     const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;
     
     console.log('We have a notification to send to : ', receiver_id);
     
     if(!event.data.val()) 
     {
      return console.log('A notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);
     }
     
     
     const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${receiver_id}/device_token`).once('value');
     
     
     return deviceToken.then(response => 
     {
      const token_id = result.val();
      
      const payload = 
      {
       notification: 
       {
        title: "Friend Request",
        body: "You have a new friend request",
        icon: "default"
       }
      };
      
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
                  .then(response => 
         {
          console.log('This was the notification feature');
         });
         });     
       });
```

how do i fix this issue? my friend used the same code and it got uploaded successfully without errors

Answer (score 0):

The error message from ESLint is this:

```
41:25  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
```

The code it's complaining about is this:

```
                       .then(response => 
                       {
                           console.log('This was the notification feature');
                       });
```

The message is saying that every then() method callback should return a value or throw an exception.  It might help if you simply `return null` from that callback after the log.

You also have a warning about nested promises.  It's more readable for your code to not use then() within a another then().  You can simply chain them on each other at the same level to get the same effect.